# How do i write Decoding function Using Conditional operator in java

Tags: java, c++, conditional-statements, talend, tmap

We are trying to map data using Talend DI tool. In that, we have to capture transformation which is related to Conditional operator.(Because of limitation of tool it won't allow if-then-else syntax instead it does support conditional operator.

**Sample Data :**

I am  trying to write this expression  into talend tmap component .  How to write this expression into tmap  component expression builder using ternary operator. Additional, i have to check for null values.

```
case when [TCode]='(00) PRE-PAID' then '00'when[TCode]='(01) C.O.D.' then '01'when[TCode]='(02) EOM' then '02'when[TCode]='10' then '(10) NET 10 DAYS'when[TCode]='15' then '(15) NET 15 DAYS'when[TCode]='21' then '(21) 2 % 30 NET 31'when[TCode]='23' then '(23) 2% NET 30 DAYS'when[TCode]='3' then '(3) CHECK'when[TCode]='30' then '(30) NET 30 DAYS' else [TCode]end as TCode
```

**Tried this conditional operator :**

```
"(00) PRE-PAID".equals(row.tCode) ?"00"  :
 "(01) C.O.D".equals(row.tCode) ?"01" :
"(02) EOM".equals(row.tCode) ? "02" :
"Unknown"
```

**Getting error when tried above conditional operator  :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    XML_API_tXMLMap_1 cannot be resolved to a type
    XML_API_tXMLMap_1 cannot be resolved to a type
    Syntax error on token ""(00) PRE-PAID"", delete this token
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you post the full compilation error?

Comment: Just a conditional expression is not going to compile, you need to assign or return the result.

Comment: @Kerry here is more description of error : http://paste.ofcode.org/39v84vUZR6r9AwQnUS52M6X

Comment: @JornVernee  you need to assign or return the result? as in ?

Comment: Well... ```String result = <conditional expr>``` or ```return <conditional expr>```.

Comment: @JornVernee  talend data integration tool  accepts  syntax  for if/else /conditional operator like this  - condition?value if true:value if false  let's say minVal = a < b ? a : b: for single statement

Comment: @JornVernee Checking talend documentation String result = <conditional expr> or return <conditional expr>. how to use this . i will get back to you .

Comment: @vickps I didn't understand you were inputting it into some GUI, (in that case there might be an example in the docs).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115583/discussion-between-vickps-and-jorn-vernee).

Comment: That looks better, but you are using a tool I don't know about. I can't help you any further.

Comment: it looks like expression is ok only i have to check null condition in it .because it is throwing null exception error

Comment: @Kerry is there way to check null condition with  conditional  expression

Comment: `object == null` .. but I think I misunderstand your question or problem

Comment: @Kerry may i know which portion of question is  creating misunderstand .so that i can bring more information to you .  here is i  have implemented object==null :please have a look on complete description in link . http://paste.ofcode.org/33S4GKPcMaSMyehzWF2vxcg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis**

According to the [link in your comment](http://paste.ofcode.org/33S4GKPcMaSMyehzWF2vxcg), you try to execute the following:

```
row1.tcode==null?null:row1.tcode.length()==0?null:row1.tcode.toUpperCase()
"(00) PRE-PAID".equals(row.tCode) ?"00"  :
"(01) C.O.D".equals(row.tCode) ?"01" :
"(02) EOM".equals(row.tCode) ? "02" :
"Unknown"
```

and you are getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    XML_API_tXMLMap_1 cannot be resolved to a type
    XML_API_tXMLMap_1 cannot be resolved to a type
    Syntax error on token ""(00) PRE-PAID"", delete this token
```

NOTE: *Java is a case sensitive language. So either **tcode** or **tCode** is correct, not both.*

**Explanation**

You provided two separate rows of code and Java doesn't know how to interpret this.

Your first line of code is (usually ended with a `;`):

```
row1.tcode==null?null:row1.tcode.length()==0?null:row1.tcode.toUpperCase()
```

and the second line (albeit it has more lines in itself it is seen as "one line") of code is:

```
"(00) PRE-PAID".equals(row.tCode) ?"00"  :
"(01) C.O.D".equals(row.tCode) ?"01" :
"(02) EOM".equals(row.tCode) ? "02" :
"Unknown"
```

We need to put those two instructions together.

**Solution**

```
(row1.tCode != null && !row1.tCode.equals("")) ? (
"(00) PRE-PAID".equals(row.tCode.toUpperCase()) ? "00" :
"(01) C.O.D".equals(row.tCode.toUpperCase()) ? "01" :
"(02) EOM".equals(row.tCode.toUpperCase()) ? "02" :
"Unknown") : "Unknown"
```

Alternatively, to shorten the first row, you could set a *Default* value for `tCode` if that makes any sense. The default value could be `""` and you don't have to check for `null` anymore. Again, this depends on your use case.